# Name and unique id of component

Tags: vue.js

### Premise

Let's assume in component we have template like this:

```
<div id="my-component-1"></div>
```

and component is registered as `my-component`.

### Question

Is it possible, from inside of component to compile that kind of id? Ideally, I want a mixin with prop `id`, that defaults to `component_name + '-' + unique_id`.

### Example

**html**

```
<my-component></my-component>
<my-component></my-component>
<other-component></other-component>
<other-component></other-component>
```

**compiled html**

```
<div id="my-component-1"></div>
<div id="my-component-2"></div>
<div id="other-component-3"></div>
<div id="other-component-4"></div>
```

---

Thanks for your determination.

Comment: I think you got to be more specific. Are you trying to dynamically set component's ID from within a component?

Comment: @AmirR. yes, compile ~= dynamically set. I'll add an example in moment.

Comment: Do you need to create dynamic `id` s only? Or some custom attribute will also work? Or maybe classes?  It's very easy to make classes and other attributes dynamic... To do the same with IDs is a small headache.

Comment: @notANerdDev no, the point is to seamlessly get the component `_uid` and  name. I surely can pass name as `props` and generate some id by global helper, which is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: @notANerdDev
In case you're intrested, I got the answer: `unique_id: this._uid, component_name: this.constructor.name`

Comment: you should post your answer to help others with the same issue. I mean post the details, and if you have time, maybe a jsfiddle too

Comment: @YerkoPalma For some reason i decided OP can't answer for two days after post. Derp. Currently I'm struggling with fiddle and it [doesn't work very well](https://jsfiddle.net/xf87n4yj/1/) with CND version of `vue.js`. Probably, it's either `browserify` or `vueify` that compiles components into classes.

Comment: I don't think that fiddle can render browserify or webpack modules properly. I saw in vue site that they provide a vue.js template for fiddle, and everything was working fine there

Answer (score 2):

### Inconsistent behavior

The undergoing solution doesn't work anything like expected. Sometimes it works just fine. Other time it produces `vue` and `vue-component` instead of `my-component`.

---

Here's the `mixin` that works for me:

```
Vue.mixin({
    props: {
        id: {
            default: function() {
                var component_name = _.kebabCase(this.constructor.name);

                if (component_name.substring(0, 3) === 'vm-')
                component_name = component_name.substring(3)

                return component_name + '-' + this._uid
            },
        },
    }
});
```

And here's what it does:

Not compiled: `<vm-my-component></vm-my-component>`

Compiled: `<div id="my-component-1"></div>`

Template: `<div :id="id"></div>`

This method works on `browserify`/`vueify` build. And doesn't work on CDN version of `vue.js`. Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xf87n4yj/1/) for details.

---

If someone tested the method on webpack/AMD — be sure to post. I'll update the answer.